# Am trying to create a stored procedure in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Am trying to get a field and if it doesn't exist, I wish to insert it into the table but am having an error. For the first query I tried

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_val( IN pid VARCHAR(30), IN pyd VARCHAR(50), IN dat VARCHAR(20), OUT value VARCHAR(50)  )
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @id AS VARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @id = paymentid FROM table WHERE phoneid=pid
    IF @id IS NULL
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO user_info (phoneid, paymentid, created_at) VALUES (pid, pyd, dat) 
       SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    SELECT @id
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @id AS VARCHAR(50) SELECT @id = paymentid FROM table WHERE phoneid=' at line 3

so I couldn't fix this and I tried this new query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_val( IN pid VARCHAR(30), IN pyd VARCHAR(50), IN dat VARCHAR(20), OUT value VARCHAR(50)  )
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT phoneid FROM user_info WHERE phoneide=pid) THEN
           SELECT paymentid FROM user_info WHERE phoneid=pid
        ELSE
           INSERT INTO user_info (phoneid, paymentid, created_at) VALUES (pid, pyd, dat) 
           SELECT paymentid FROM user_info WHERE phoneid=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END IF
```

but I also get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE THEN INSERT INTO user_info (phoneid, paymentid, created_at) VAL' at line 5

Maybe my understanding of forming complex queries is off but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change you `Stored Procedure` as below (check the changes from comments):

```
DELIMITER $$   // change delimiter
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_val( IN pid VARCHAR(30), IN pyd VARCHAR(50), IN dat VARCHAR(20), OUT VALUE VARCHAR(50)  )
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT phoneid FROM user_info WHERE phoneide=pid) THEN
           SELECT paymentid FROM user_info WHERE phoneid=pid; // use semicolon
        ELSE 
           INSERT INTO user_info (phoneid, paymentid, created_at) VALUES (pid, pyd, dat);// use semicolon
           SELECT paymentid FROM user_info WHERE phoneid=SCOPE_IDENTITY();// use semicolon
        END IF;// use semicolon
        END;// use end and semicolon
```